# How to make my code cleaner in this case (switch case / if else)

Tags: php, coding-style

I am designing a small web game using PHP. 
There are several buttons in the game, which will ajax request when player click.

When I need to do different determination on each button, I write down the following code...

```
    if ($button != 'A') {
        if ($button == 'B') {
            if (!$this->functionB()) {
                return $this->returnJson(<some message>);
            }
        } elseif ($button == 'C') {
            if (!$this->functionC()) {
                return $this->returnJson(<some message>);
            }
        } else {  // other buttons go here
            if (!$this->myFunction($button)) {
                return $this->returnJson(<some message>);
            }
        }
    }

    // other logic...

    return $this->returnJson(<success message>);
```

When player click button A, he will absolutely get success message.
When player click button B, he will get error message if he doesn't pass the determination through functionB(). If he pass, he will get success message. So is clicking button C.
When player click other buttons (around 10 buttons), the determination will be done by myFunction().

But I think the code is not elegant since there are three layer of if-else statement. So I try to change it to switch-case statement.

```
    switch ($button) {
        case ('A'):
            break;
        case ('B') {
            if (!$this->functionB()) {
                return $this->returnJson(<some message>);
            }
            break;
        case ('C') {
            if (!$this->functionC()) {
                return $this->returnJson(<some message>);
            }
            break;
        default: // other buttons go here
            if (!$this->myFunction($button)) {
                return $this->returnJson(<some message>);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    // other logic...

    return $this->returnJson(<success message>);
```

I am still not satisfied at this because there are if statement in switch statement.

How to make my code cleaner in this case?

I am new in programming, and really want to establish good foundation on my coding style.
Hope you can give my some suggestion. Thanks a lot!

Comment: following may be useful    http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/205803/how-to-tackle-a-branched-arrow-head-anti-pattern

Comment: you can to use several and complete ifs... but try to uniform the use of "!=" or "=="... I prefer only to use "=="... and you can store the out in a var, and only sets for each if, and returns only a time at the end

Answer (score 0):

Personally the case statement you've shown below looks readable, and is functional. I've found from experience that cryptic is definitely not the way to go, even if you have some repeating lines. You're not even really repeating lines, though. If you were to try to separate out into functions, it would look quite redundant having functions within functions.

I do see one thing, instead of returning from within case, program flow should normally follow to the end of the function, otherwise you end up with unreachable code or hard-to-troubleshoot situations. Your code above, for example I think you may have accidentally done this, so I hope it helps with my point.

So for example, instead of going:

```
return myFunction($param);
```

Use this:

```
$returnVal=myFunction($param);
```

Then at the end, have it flow to:
    return $returnVal;

Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service locator-esque pattern: at application start-up you'd load the functions into a key / value collection with the key being the button name and the function being the value. When the call comes in you'd do something like:

```
var handler = collection[ incomingValue ];

handler.Invoke();
```

(I'm a C# developer so translate it into PHP! :D)